# Get request works in POSTMAN, but doesn't in axios

Tags: axios, postman, nuxt.js

I am developin with Vue and Nuxt frameworks. All my fetch and get go through axios. Testing get request succeed in POSTMAN, but when i write in axios in returns opposite.

All I do in POSTMAN is passing 1 header to API:

`key: Cookie` `value: session_coupons_id=some_value;`

Response is positive.

When I try to pass same using axios in my Nuxt project it fails:

```
axios({
        url: 'https://some.com/api/v2/coupons/?page=1',
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
          Cookie: 'session_coupons_id=some_value',
        },
      })
```

Thank you. Ask questions for more detail

Comment: I have this problem too -- I am trying to use django token authentication and it would appear that axios is either not sending the headers or django is rejecting them even though they look the same as they do in Postman... Perhaps the folks who wrote Postman could help the folks who wrote axios? :-)